# 'Could not resolve all dependencies..' error when resolving Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error when including the Firebase Auth library. This error only comes up if I include **Firebase auth 11.8.0**. Upon removing that, gradle builds successfully. Is there an incompatibility of the versions I use?

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    def googleSupportVersion = '26.1.0'
    def googlePlayServicesVersion = '11.8.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$googleSupportVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/11.8.0/firebase-auth-11.8.0.aar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/11.8.0/firebase-auth-11.8.0.aar'.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Looks like you're just having problems downloading it:  "Could not get resource", "Could not HEAD".

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried on different networks as well. It only happens if I attempt to download the firebase-auth depen.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what the problem is.  I've been using firebase-auth 11.8.0 for over a month now, and I've never heard of this before.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks Doug. Then it's not related to firebase-auth. I will keep looking